# How to find $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-x^2) \, dx$ with contour integration?

Tags: contour-integration, gaussian-integral

Contour integration is a very powerful tool.

But what if a function has no poles or zero's ?

For instance :

How to find $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-x^2) \, dx$ with contour integration?

Comment: You can integrate $e^{-\pi x^2}$ using contour integration.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1266856/gaussian-integral-using-contour-integration-with-a-parallelogram-contour/1267512#1267512

Comment: what reason do you have to think you **can** use  Contour Integration to find this integral?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the classic approach is as follows: take a rectangular contour where one side is $[-R,R]$, and the other is $[-R,R] + \alpha i$ for $\alpha > 0$.

Comment: @user247327: You can.  See my comment above yours.

Comment: @user247327 everything is possible if you believe in the power of Contours

Comment: @Jonas: Wrong.  Not a duplicate - question here explicitly asks about using contour integration, no solution in your link uses it.

Comment: @Jonas: I did read the posts - all of them.  And my poor eyes could not find anything related to contour integration.  Maybe your definition of contour integration differs from mine and the OP's, but please, help me understand which of the posts in your link are directed to contour integration.

Comment: You can have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-mathrme-x2-dx-dfrac-sqrt-pi2/147143#147143

Comment: @Jonas: What on earth does that have to do with contour integration?  It evaluates the integral using the Poisson sum formula.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: actually, the approach is to integrate $$\oint_C dz \frac{e^{-\pi z^2}}{\sin{\pi z}} $$ where $C$ is a $45^{\circ}$ parallelogram.

Comment: @Ragnar: Although the question in that link is the same, no solution actually uses contour integration.  The only solution offered is quite nonsensical and useless.  I would thus not mark this question as a duplicate of the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform an integration of certain functions that have no poles by performing a contour integration of another function that may have poles (or a branch cut) in order to transform the contour integral into the sought-after integral.  In this case, one may consider

$$\oint_C dz \frac{e^{-\pi z^2}}{\sin{\pi z}} $$

where $C$ is a parallelogram in the complex plane, where $C= C_1+C_2+C_3+C_4$:

Along $C_1$, $z=-1/2 + e^{i \pi/4} t$, $t \in [R,-R]$.

Along $C_2$, $z=x-i (R/\sqrt{2})$, $x \in \left [-1/2-R/\sqrt{2},1/2-R/\sqrt{2} \right ]$.

Along $C_3$, $z=1/2 + e^{i \pi/4} t$, $t \in [-R,R]$.

Along $C_4$, $z=x+i (R/\sqrt{2})$, $x \in \left [-1/2+R/\sqrt{2},1/2+R/\sqrt{2} \right ]$.

One then completes the evaluation by taking the limit as $R \to \infty$. By adding the integrals along $C_1$ and $C_3$, the gaussian integral is reproduced.  One then shows that the integrals about $C_2$ and $C_4$ vanish in the limit as $R \to \infty$. For details of the evaluation, see [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1266856/gaussian-integral-using-contour-integration-with-a-parallelogram-contour/1267512#1267512).

Comment: I downvoted because you didn't say if in your opinion it is only a (counter)example or if there is a general method behind it, and you didn't explain how to think to that transformation of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx $ to $\lim_{R \to \infty} \oint_{C(R)} f(z) g(z) dz$ and how to choose $g(z)$ or "why" it is related to the former : so please tell us more or give a reference !

Comment: @user1952009: thanks for posting that.  There are other examples, I just chose to tackle the one the OP put out there.  That's why contour integration techniques are at the same time so powerful and yet so difficult to master: there is so much freedom in choosing a contour and/or integrand to produce an integral.  But there really isn't anything I am aware of in the way of systematic techniques.  If I encounter a nonstandard example, I experiment and play and poke until I get what I want.  It is a messy process few people have the patience for.  If you want, I will post another example.

Comment: so you found it nearly "by chance" ? oh I just saw that Ragnar in his related answer posted a link on that trick : it has been discovered only in ~1910 or 1940 !

Comment: @user1952009: This one?  No, I learned how to do this from someone else.  However, I have other examples of, say, rectangular contours and really bizarre integrands that lead to specified integrals that I did discover myself.  Again, time permitting, I will get a link to you.  As for the gaussian...I guess, not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

It can be found by using a rectangular contour and the function
 $$
\frac{e^{-z^2/2}}{1-e^{-\sqrt{\pi}(1+i)z}}.
$$

See the eighth proof in [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/gaussianintegral.pdf) for the motivation and analysis.