# Contours for the integral that contains $exp(-x^2)$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm interested in the integral

$$
 \int_0^\infty dx \frac{e^{i b x - c x^2}}{x^2 + a^2} 
$$

where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are all positive real numbers. 
What contours should I choose to evaluate this integral 
using residue theorem? Can it even be done in this case?

Comment: It is not trivial that it is possible, since the value of the integral for $a=c=1$ and $b\to 0^+$ is non-elementary ($\frac{\pi e}{2}\text{Erfc}(1)$).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1266856/gaussian-integral-using-contour-integration-with-a-parallelogram-contour/1267512#1267512

Comment: I think a closed form solution might be available if one replaces $\exp(ibx)$ by $\cos(bx)$

Comment: but without residue theorem