# Suitable contour for an integral ($\Gamma(1/2)$)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Consider the following integral
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx=\sqrt{\pi}$$

This can be evaluated using contour integration methods. A similar question was asked before (unfortunately I could not find the link), however the person who answered did not provide the contour but said "Choose a suitable contour noting that $z=0$ is a branch point". Unfortunately I could not find a suitable contour for this problem with this integrand. The problem is probably that this function doesn't have any useful poles.

Could someone indicate what kind of contour works for this problem? You can even add poles if it helps to somehow evaluate above but without changing the integrand too much.

Comment: I doubt there is a straight forward method because $\sqrt{\pi}$ can't be deduced from poles evaluation. The evaluation of the integral depends on   $$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-x^2} = \sqrt{\pi}$$ after substitution.

Comment: Seems like there may be easier ways to evaluate that integral, but a suitable contour should be a "keyhole" type.  Big outer circle of radius $R$, approach the origin above the positive $x$-axis, small circle of radius $\epsilon$ around the origin, back out to the outer circle below the positive $x$-axis.

Comment: That contour will fail to yield anything useful since $e^{-z}$ diverges as $\text{Re}(z)\to -\infty$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1266856/221811 has references.

Comment: See the answer posted by @t.b. [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34767/int-infty-infty-e-x2-dx-with-complex-analysis) for another way forward.

Comment: @ Everyone: Thanks guys. What I was referring to was an answer someone had posted to this problem in some other post saying that "You can choose a suitable contour...". Guess the answer to this problem is, "Not this way". I recall reading in a book that the above integral was assumed unsolvable via contour methods until Polya found a way.