# Gaussian integral with complex argument

Tags: contour-integration, complex-integration, gaussian-integral

I'm trying to show

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt\frac{\pi}{a}$$

where $a$ is a complex number.

I made the substitution $x=y\sqrt{\bar a}$, where $\bar a $ is $a$ conjugate.

$$\Rightarrow \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx=\sqrt{\bar a}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lvert a \rvert^2 y^2}dy \tag 1$$
$$=\sqrt{\bar a}I$$
where the standard Integral $I$ (evaluated by contour integration) is $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt\frac{\pi}{\lvert a \rvert ^2}$
$$\Rightarrow\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\bar a}}{2}\sqrt\frac{\pi}{\lvert a \rvert ^2}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt\frac
{\pi}{a}$$

But I never used the fact that $Re(a)>0$ which is necessary for the convergence. Can anyone point out where is the mistake in above? I suspect it is in the integration limits when changing the variables.

Does anyone know how to evaluate the integral using contour?

Comment: Square root is not a well defined function on the complex plane and you are not allowed to make substitutions like $x=y\sqrt {\overline {a}}$

Comment: You deal with complex functions. Therefore, as you seem to be aware about it, integration cannot be thought any longer on the real line but on a **closed contour** (rectangular in this case).

Comment: Here is a link : (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/34772). Another one (more sophisticated) : (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1267512).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can the ambiguity be removed by saying that I choose the principle root?

Comment: @aneetkumar The rulse of Calculus you have learnt for real valued functioins of a real variable cannot be blindly applied to the complex case. The substitution you made is not valid.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks. But the links do not talk about integrals with a complex argument. Sorry for if I'm not able to see if it is obvious to figure out integrals with complex arguments from the methods in the link. I explicitly tried to perform contour integral but seem to get infinite value for integration over non-real-line part of the contour (contour being (0,0) $\rightarrow$ (p,0) $\rightarrow$(p,-p)  with limit p $\rightarrow \infty$ )

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see. What if I switch to complex variable ($x\rightarrow z$) and pick up an appropriate contour (e.g. the one I mentioned in a comment to Jean above) and then make the substitution? But doing so, I'm guessing, would only change the shape of the contour and no part of it would lie on real axis then.