# Alternative methods of evaluating the Gaussian integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-z^2}dz$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-integration, gaussian-integral

A long while ago (at university) I learned the following (fairly standard) method for evaluating $I:=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-z^2}dz$ by squaring $I$ then using polar coordinates:

$$
\begin{align}
I^2 &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-z^2}dz \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-z^2}dz
\\ &= 4\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-y^2}dy
\\ &= 4\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}e^{-y^2}dxdy
\\ &= 4\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy
\\ &= 4\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-r^2}rdrd\theta
\\ &= 2\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}re^{-r^2}dr
\\ &= \pi \left[ -e^{-r^2} \right]_{0}^{\infty}
\\ &= \pi
\end{align}
\\
\\ \implies I=\sqrt{\pi}
$$

I remember being amazed at the ingenuity of that first line: squaring $I$ in order to turn the single integral into a double integral.

I am curious whether any other methods are known for evaluating $I$. Especially methods that do not begin by squaring $I$.

I have not been able to do anything worthwhile with it myself. My research has yielded [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#By_Cartesian_coordinates) method that does not require polar coordinates but still begins by squaring $I$. I have also considered complex integration using a clever contour but have not managed to complete a method.

Does anybody know of any other methods?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846671/calculate-the-gauss-integral-without-squaring-it-first

Comment: A duplicate question! Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to integrate
$$\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty x\exp(-x^2(1+y^2))\,dx\,dy=
\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty x\exp(-x^2(1+y^2))\,dy\,dx$$
both ways. The first gives
$$\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{dy}{1+y^2}=\frac\pi4$$
and the second gives
$$\left(\int_0^\infty \exp(-t^2)\,dt
\right)^2.$$

Comment: (+1) Nicely written.  Succinct and sufficient.